# 415 (Unsupported Media Type) from browser when callign JAX-RS API in embedded tomcat server

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, jquery, jax-rs

I am getting  415 (Unsupported Media Type) from browser when I try to upload csv formatted excel file through the JAX-RS rest API. Web Appliation was deployed and running under embedded Tomcat server.

I am able to upload csv file successfully If I deploy my web application in tomcat 7 server which is not the embedded tomcat.

I appreciate your inputs to resolve my issue.

> URL: ipaddress:8090/config/configutil/upload

### Failed Browser Header Request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8090/config/configutil/upload
Request Method:POST
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2346
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarycWT1QSyGGxijtUUP
Host:localhost:8090
Origin:http://localhost:8090
Referer:http://localhost:8090/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundarycWT1QSyGGxijtUUP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UserExportFormat"

XML
------WebKitFormBoundarycWT1QSyGGxijtUUP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedFile"; filename="1-06092012 (3).csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel


------WebKitFormBoundarycWT1QSyGGxijtUUP--
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:1117
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 18 Sep 2012 00:09:35 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

### JAX-RS API

```
/**
     * API will import the ConfigSet from CSV file request and returns the response in Text/Html format.
     * @param is
     * @param request
     * @param response
     */


@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public void upload(@FormDataParam("uploadedFile") InputStream is, @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    // read it with BufferedReader

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        ConfigSetResponse configSetResponse = new CSVReader().csvReader(br);
        out = response.getWriter();
        mapper.writeValue(out, configSetResponse);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while uploading :", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Close the file once all data has been read.
        try {
            if (null != br) {
                br.close();
            }
            if (null != is) {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error while uploading :", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Java Script code to invoke this JAX-RS API:

```
var importForm = $( modal ).find("#icwExportForm");                 


                        importForm.ajaxForm({
                            contentType: false,
                            success : function(responseObj) {
                                try{



                                    refreshConfigSetUI(eval(responseObj));
                                    ccw.modal.hide(modal);
                                }catch(e){
                                    ccw.modal.hide(modal);
                                    $('#runtimeErrorMessages').html(commonErrorData);                                   
                                }
                            },
                            error : function(request, msg,  err) {
                                ccw.modal.hide(modal);
                                $('#runtimeErrorMessages').html(commonErrorData);
                            }
                        });

                        importForm.attr("action", "config/configutil/upload");
                        importForm.attr("Content-Type" ,"multipart/form-data");
                        importForm.submit();
                    });
```

### HTML Page:

```
<form class="icwExportForm" id="icwExportForm"   method="post" action="" name="ExportOptionInputForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">

<div class="icwImportContent" style="padding: 5px 0px 10px 20px">
                    <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" value="" id="icwUploadFile" class="icwButton" size="45"  tabindex="1" />

</div>

</form>
```

Comment: The `Content-Type` HTTP Header is set as per the expectation of the JAX-RS method you paste above, but i see a `boundary=----` in the Request trace log. I'm not sure if that's the culprit here.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But when I deploy same web application in tomcat 7 server (which is not embedded) I am not getting 415 unsupported error from browser. See below success header request.

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:8080/ConfigLite/config/configutil/upload
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:6467
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryH6x1m2vr8SBat1fS
Cookie:local="9148@ASVINNAK-WS01"
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/ConfigLite/

Comment: Found the solution for this problem. After mentioned the mimepull.jar under META-INF file the file import is working. Now 415 unsupported media type error is resolved.

Comment: Aswani, if you could explain the workaround/fix in more details and post it as an answer, it would be helpful for others.